# Angular routerLink w/o "[]"

Tags: angular

```
<a [routerLink]="..."/>
<a routerLink="..."/>
```

I see in the tutorial they've used two types of syntaxes for **routerLink** attribute.

I cannot find any documents which tell the differences between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something that is very important to know about Angular! 
when you are using [] around you're property it means that it equal to some variable from the script and if it is not covered by this [] is just the string is equal to

this is the two ways to get TS variables to the template

ts

```
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {
    someLinkFromTheTS:string = "/home";
    }
```

html

```
<a [routerLink]="someLinkFromTheTS"/>
<a routerLink="{{someLinkFromTheTS}}"/>
```

And if you do not want to use variables

```
<a routerLink="/home"/>
```

> The brackets tell Angular to evaluate the template expression. If you omit the brackets, Angular treats the string as a constant and initializes the target property with that string.
>
> this is a very important concept

Answer (score 3):

From the [Angular Guide](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#remember-the-brackets):

> **Remember the brackets**
>
> The brackets tell Angular to evaluate the template expression. If you omit the brackets, Angular treats the string as a constant and initializes the target property with that string. It does not evaluate the string!